# Checking every bit is on some cycle

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-theory

I'm coding a model where :

Node are represented as bitvectors of 10 length each representing some molecules and edges can take any molecules that was present at source to  to a target node.

for example

> S_Node      : 0b0100000011   // Molecule 0 , 1 , 8 present on node
>
> One_Edge    : 0b0000000010    // Molecule 1 is going out on edge

I have to enforce condition that **each outgoing Molecule on edge is coming back to the source node on some cycle**. Molecule has to come back in a cycle means that during taking path of the cycle it has to be present on evry node and evry edge it takes. 
* Parallel edges are allowed.

Molecule 1 takes path  S_Node -> Node_1 -> Node_2 ... -> S_Node. So Molecule 1 started from S_Node on an edge and traveled through  Node_1 ... and came back to S_Node on a cycle. Hence this molecule satisfies the condition. 
Similarly i have to check for each molecule on each edge.

I'm doing in trivial possible way of checking for each nodes what are possible edges going out and then for each edge what are possible bits that are present and enforcing each coming back on some cycle.

```
for  (i = 0; i < N; i++) {       // for each Node 
  for (j = 0; j < E; j++) {      // for each Edge going out frm node i
  // Lets say we have some way of finding E  
      if(edgeWeight & (1 << j)) {    //All outgoing bits
           // Enforcing that each will come  back 
           // On some Cycle
```

Its easily visible that i have to iterate over all nodes and then all edges going out and then for each bits on those edges, have to write code for enforcing the same. Enforcing itself have to iterate over at least no.Of Nodes #N.

Any better way to efficiently do this ? Any other way to check for same thing in graph theory ? Thanks

Comment: The description is very unclear, if you ask me...

Comment: Will try to improve.

Comment: So, if I understand right, you want to build a graph without "dead ends" (leaves)? Or you want just to check it?

Comment: Is that checking dead ends will be enough to satisfy that each molecule going out coming back. I'm not sure, i think its not. I have to check.

Comment: You better be sure about it, as it is understanding of your problem. Anyway, it is still not clear. Can a molecule present on more than one node? Can it present on more than one edge? Can it present on both, node and edge? It looks to me that the data representation is not very appropriate for this problem..

Comment: As i have mentioned that molecule has to come back in a cycle means that during taking path of the cycle it has to be present on evry node and evry edge it takes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99248/discussion-between-user2754673-and-eugene-sh).

Comment: If I understand you have to enforce the cycle where each 'bit' (molecule) will cycle `S_Node -> Node_1 -> Node_2 ... -> S_Node`, then it appears you could check/enforce with a *single loop* and check by `S_Node & Node_1 & Node_2 ...` for each bit, validating the cycle when the result of the `&` is `1`.

Comment: True ... @David .. But we don't know Which are the edges and nodes so at the end we have to and them and check what you have suggested, So completely right.  Also Its not just checking dead end. For ex : a simple  three node. 
Node : [1] [2] [3] ................... Edge[1][2] , Edge[2][3] , Edge[3][2] .. There is no dead end ... as from 1 i can go to 2 and from 2 can go to three and from three i can go to 2 back ... But any molecule that might have present on edge between Edge[1][2] has no way to come back on a cycle.

Comment: I have said enforcing have to iterate to N cause it can come back in one edge also but can take longer route. So N-1 hops. Or if i allow complex cycles then total no of edges -1 . But you are dead right that it has to and all, i'm kind'of anding all. Thanks –

Comment: That is where it was a bit unclear. From the original, it appeared you were concerned about the cycle for a particular 'bit-position' on each node (your example bit-1). If it were as simple as checking for a cycle at each bit position, then *anding* for each connected node at each bit-position in a single loop would work. How do you first determine *"on which node a cycle begins?"*. and *"how do you determine the uniqueness of each connection?"* (e.g.that `S_Node(bit-1)` and `X_Node(bit-1)` are both attached to the same molecule?

Comment: on which node a cycle begins?" > I have to check for each Molecule. So i'm starting at Node 1 and then for all edges that are going out , and for each molecule at each edge that is going out i have to make sure that its coming back on a cycle. Then check same for all other nodes. I don't have to take care about uniqueness. Or can you elaborate on uniqueness. By that u mean what if two molecules on same edge taking same cycle. That's allowed

Comment: Isn't this question awfully localized?

Comment: @Chimera I think the check is global. The condition is a global condition. Local check would be just checking total different types of molecule leaving from a node coming back to its source , hence not enforcing have to come back on cycle.  And if that was sarcasm .. then hahhahahha....

Comment: Is `10` the maximum number of molecules?  Or can there be many molecules, but each one is limited to ten links with other molecules?  (weak bonds?)  Why is an edge a 10-bit vector with only one set bit, rather than the log2 of that (i.e. a number from 0-9, which fits in 4 bits, making for a compact representation).  shifting a `1` to an arbitrary position, and the inverse ([finding the position of the first or last set bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set)) are both very fast operations for CPUs.  (ISO C doesn't standardize a `ffs` function, though.  POSIX does.)

Comment: Yes. 10 is max no of molecules. Lets see them as distinct from each other. Coz if node contain all 1's 0b1111111111 an edge can be of form 0b1111111111 i.e all present molecule is going out on that edge. You are absolutely spot on that we could represent edge as compact version, But then we'll loose the structure and doing bitwise & | would be really difficult as this is only one part of the whole project model. Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a directed graph per molecule (per bit) Simply do your trick to check for any non-cycles per molecule.

You can take btillys way of checking for cycles, another option is to look at [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component). You essentially want each subgraph (for a given molecule) to be a graph where each [connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) is actually strongly connected. There are some good algorithms to for strongly connected components referred to from the wikipedia article linked to earlier.

Comment: wich , bang on . This was the other way available for each molecule you have check for the trajectories it takes and then make sure that's scc or just check if that defy the total molecules coming in are different than going out. As i have not found any scalable way to do it trivially, i'll do it this way. Problem was to state it declarative i.e  state it rather than check it. Coz if all that i need is checking then i can do it in linear time tarzen algo. Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

The representation of nodes is irrelevant to the problem.  You have a directed graph.  You wish to verify that for every node and edge, there exists a cycle containing that edge.  And you want to be reasonably efficient about it (rather than doing a brute force search for all possible cycles from all edges).

Here is an observation.  Suppose that you find a cycle in your graph `G`.  Consider the graph `G'` which is the same as your original graph EXCEPT that the cycle has been collapsed down to a single node.  The answer to your question for `G` is the same as the answer to your question for `G'` because any cycle in `G` leads to a cycle in `G'` (possibly a self-intersecting one that can be turned into 2 cycles), and any cycle in `G'` leads to a cycle in `G` (if you hit the collapsed node, then follow its cycle around until you find the exit point to continue).

So now the question goes from brute force discovery of cycles to collapsing cycles until you have a small graph where the question is easily answered.  So for each node, for each edge, you start a path.  Your path continues until you have discovered a cycle.  Any cycle.  (Not necessarily back to the original node!)  Collapse that cycle, and keep traveling until you either have to backtrack (in which case your condition is not met) or you manage to loop back to your original node, collapse that cycle, and move on to another edge.

If you implement this, you'll have a polynomial algorithm, but not the best you can do.  The problem is that creating new graphs with a cycle collapsed is an expensive operation.  But there is a trick that helps.  Instead of collapsing the graph every time you find a cycle, try to be lazy about it.  Create a new "fake node" for that cycle, and mark each node in that cycle as going to that fake one.  Every time you see an edge that goes to a node, do a recursive search through those mappings to the most collapsed node that you've found, and mark everything you saw in that search as directly mapping there.

If you implement the lazy bit well, your overall algorithm should wind up `O(E)` where `E` is the number of edges in your graph.  You actually can't do better than that given that you have to visit every edge no matter what you do.

Comment: I don't think the collapsing works for the original problem. If I get the OP right what he actually has is a multiplexed directed graph, i.e. one graph for each bit in his bitvectors. One could do what you propose for each bit of course.

Comment: Reading more closely, you are clearly right.  That said, I believe that doing what I propose for each bit is going to be the right approach.